# Gradle - How to include a local library in the output jar

Tags: java, gradle

My Gradle project has a couple of maven dependencies. I don't want those included in my jar. It also has some dependencies on local jars. How can i include the classes from those in the output jar?

Comment: Hmm.. If You don't include the dependencies, the resulting artifact can not be run. Have a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a local repository (a directory in this case) with the following:

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        // URL can refer to a local directory
        url "../local-repo"
    }
}
```

To exclude the dependent jars from your final jar, you can use the compile configuration like this:

```
compileOnly files('libs/jgrapht-jdk1.6.jar')
compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7'
```

A more detailed answer can be seen over here:
[Gradle dependencies local jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231855/gradle-dependencies-local-jar-file)